# How to resume an activity?

Tags: android

Suppose there are three activity,the display order is a->b->c.
Now, I would like to resume the Activity a directly,after `Activity` c complete some operations.
Resume the `Activity` a by `Activity` c directly,but create a new instance of Activity a.

Comment: Why do you want a new instance of Activity a after it's gone through a->b->c->a

Comment: What, do you want to resume or restart it? Either you resume it by sending an Intent with flag ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, or you finish the old one and restart it (then you get a new instance).

Answer (score 2):

as @Matthias said, do you want to resume or restart Activity a? if you want to restart it then you would include `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` in your intent which does this: ["If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK).

or you could probably just call `finish();` in Activity a's `onPause`

if you want to resume it then you just call `startActivity(new Intent(Parent.this, ActivityA.class));` or whatever your code is

additional information: [Activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html), [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [Activity and Task Design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html)

Answer (score 2):

- In b you use `BroadcastReceiver` in `onResume()` method with content `finish()` as:

> BroadcastReceiver receiverFinish=null;
>
> ```
> @Override
>
> protected void onResume() {
>
>   super.onResume();
>   if(receiverFinish!=null){
>       unregisterReceiver(receiverFinish);
>   }
>   receiverFinish=new BroadcastReceiver() {
> ```

```
 @Override          
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


                if(intent.getAction().equals("finish.activity")){
                        MyActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                                }       };
                registerReceiver(receiverFinish, new IntentFilter("finish.activity"));

    }
```

- Then in c you call :

> //finish b activity
>
> Intent intent=new Intent("finish.activity");
>   sendBroadcast(intent);
>
> //finish c activity
>
> finish();

- Hope useful for you! good cluck!
- From **Pham Trung Phuong - Vsoft Corp**.

Comment: So it is ok to leave a receiver registered after onPause() is called?